# Can not concatenate float to string

Tags: string, concatenation

```
name = input ("What is your name? ")
age = input ("What is your age? ")
sleep = input ("How many hours do you sleep at night? ")

sleep1 = int(sleep)
age1 = int(age)

wasted_years = (sleep1/24) * age1
wasted_years1 = round(wasted_years, 2)

print("Hello "  + name)
print("You have been asleep unconscious for " + wasted_years1)
```

Comment: You need to show "working" code.  This is not a language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to produce formated respecting the given types, e.g.

```
print("You have been asleep unconscious for %.2f years." % (wasted_years1))
```

or simply convert it to a string using `str()` and concatenate

```
print("You have been asleep unconscious for " + str(wasted_years1) + " years.")
```

Comment: @EsmondKim Sure, my pleasure. If the answer was helpful, accept, and later upvote (when you have the privilege earned). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers